# AWS best way to handle high volume transactions

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability

I am writing a system that has extremely high volume of transactions, CRUD and I am working with AWS. What are the considerations that I must keep in mind given that none of the data should be lost?

I have done some research and they say to use SQS queues to make sure that data is not lost. What other backup, redundancy, quick processing considerations should I keep in mind?

Comment: You can uses SQS for buffering these txs, but have to remember that standard SQS does not guarantee order and provides at least one delivery guarantee (some txs can be duplicated). So you system should be able to handle out of order txs or duplicate txs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to create a system that is highly resilient, whilst also being redundant I would advise you to take a read of the [AWS Well Architected Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/). This will go into more detail that a person can provide on stack overflow.

Regarding individual technologies:

- If you're transactional like you said, then you should look at using a relational data store for storing the data. I'd recommend taking a look at [Amazon Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/), it has built in features like auto scaling of read onlys and multi master support. Whilst you might be expecting large number, by using autoscaling you will only pay for what you use.
- Try to decouple your APIs, have a dumb validation layer before handing off to your backend if you can help it. Technologies like SQS (as you mentioned before) help with decoupling when you combine with [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).
- SQS guarantees at least once, so if your system should not write duplicates you'll want to account for idempotency in your application.
- Also use a dead letter queue (DLQ) to handle any failed actions.
- Ensure any resources residing in your VPC are spread across availability zones.
- Use S3, EC2 Backup Manager and RDS snapshots to ensure data is backed up. Most other services has some sort of backup functionality you can enable.
- Use autoscaling wherever possible to ensure you're reducing costs.
- Build any infrastructure using an IaC tool (CloudFormation or Terraform), and any provisioning of resources via a tool like (Ansible, Puppet, Chef). Try to follow a pre baked AMI workflow to ensure that it is quick to return to the base server state.